# Minidlna gives error "Sudo: unable to resolve host <local server>"

Tags: minidlna

I got a problem with the minidlna server.

when I try to start the server minidlna give the following error.

```
 Sudo: unable to resolve host ..............
```

(The local server)

I can't find what the problem is.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This isn't a minidlna problem, and shouldn't prevent you from starting the minidlna server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix it by editing `/etc/hosts` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

(from a terminal)

I write here my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   CurrentHostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

You should have at least the first two lines with the **correct** (current) hostname in the second line. Use the command `hostname` to obtain the correct hostname.
After a while the problem should disappear.
Good editing!

Comment: Hmmm I tryed the above solution but after 1 day i still got the Sudo: unable to resolved host problem. someone else knows what to do.

Comment: Maybe I still know what to do. Your hostname must match the one in `/etc/hosts`. Check another time with `hostname` and `less /etc/hosts`: if they doesn't match, a software/user with root privileged changed them. Find the software and edit it's configuration or remove it from the boot sequence (the rc files). If you still can't solve, there is a solution I didn't mention: edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` following the guide at `http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap6sec71.html` or using `man nsswitch.conf`. Thumb up if you fix. ;-)